# Reading test images for resnet18

Tags: pytorch, resnet, transfer-learning

I am trying to read an image file and classify and image.
My model is resnet18 I trained it previously and planning to use a different .py script to classify a list of images. This is my network:

```
PATH = './net.pth'
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 16)
model_ft.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model_ft.eval()
```

And I am trying to read Images this way:

```
imsize = 256
loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(imsize), transforms.ToTensor()])
def image_loader(image_name):
    #load image, returns cuda tensor
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).float()
    image = Variable(image, requires_grad=True)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    return image.cuda()  

image = image_loader("dataset/test/9673.png")

model_ft(image)
```

I am getting this error:

```
 "Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[1, 4, 676, 256] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead"
```

I've got recommended to remove the unsqueeze for resnet18, doing that I got the following error:

```
"Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 7, 7], but got 3-dimensional input of size [4, 676, 256] instead"
```

I do not quite understand the problem I am dealing with, how should I read my test set? I'll need to write the class ID-s and the file names into a .txt afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a PNG image which has 4 channels. your network expects 3 channels.
Convert to `RGB` and you should be fine. In your `image_loader` simply do:

```py
image = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your image input is of the shape: `batch_size*4*height*width` instead of `batch_size*3*height*width`. That's why  the error. Can you do this and report the shape:

`print(image.shape)` after the call to `image_loader()`.